# How to upload multiple images on WCF in a single Request and not in bytes format

Tags: image-uploading

I searched many sites in uploading multiple images in a single request on WCF. The webservices showing in the to uploading images can be converted in to into bytes format to saving the directory. My requirement is uploading multiple images in single request and some pf the parameters also coming in the http post method. how store those images in server  using WCF?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want this?

If you make multiple request it would be more user friendly.

In Single request you can't upload multiple images and also its not recommended.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. Uploading files individually means it will takes lot of time to uploading the files. Because I have 20 images every time i will check the image is uploading or not in the server. And establish the connections every time to server to upload the files. But in the php we can upload multiple images in single request. In php we can set all images in one single request to uploading is possible. In the .Net it will possible to upload multiple images in single request?

Comment: You need to use concept of WCF i.e. Concurrency and Throttling.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/89858/WCF-Concurrency-Single-Multiple-and-Reentrant-and